# Powershell web automation - drop down list problems

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am doing some web automation (screen scraping) with PS.  I have a lot of it working fine. I am having a problem with drop down lists.

When I use  `$doc.getElementById("ddlExtractName").SelectedIndex = 2`, on some lists it changes the item in the list, but the page doesn't refresh.  It does refresh if I manually change the value in the listbox by clicking. I have no idea why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't (even on the same website).

I also am not able to access items in the list bu index.  For example, I should be able to do this:

```
$FF= $doc.getElementById("ddlFixedFileFormat")
$FF.options[$FF.SelectedIndex].text
```

That returns an error `unable to index into an object`.

Comment: What does `$FF.options | Get-Member` say about the type of object `options` returns?

Comment: I actually think I got that part. If I loop through (foreach) and look for .Selected and grab the OuterText property, that works. I think PS is not getting the kind of object I expected. When I do what you say, there are tons of properties.

Comment: Lots of properties but if you want to index that object it should have a ParameterizedProperty called something like `Item` with an int index - assuming you're indexing with an int.

Comment: There are 758 properties returned. None have item in them.

Comment: Also, if I cycle through and then set .Selected="true" for the one I want selected, it does select it, but doesn't triger a change event and the page does not update.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. I think that when the page was refreshed, I needed to refetch the document into my variable before acting on it.